Locus in the complex plane of a point $Q(w)$, $w=z+\frac2{z-1}$, where $|z-1|=2$

Let $P(z)$ be a point in a complex plane which satisfies $|z-1|=2$. Find the locus of a point $Q(w)$ which satisfies $w=z+\frac2{z-1}$.

I tried forming a quadractic equation to find z in terms of w, but that does not work. What else can I do?

Before asking any questions, search it in Approach zero website, link : https://approach0.xyz/search/

@Guruprasad Did you? I did and found nothing. @ devil, more specific link: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&p=1

@AnneBauval I am just sharing this help new users & I know it is not a duplicate question

Thank you both for your links.

$$w-1=2e^{it}+e^{-it}=3\cos t+i\sin t$$
hence the locus is the ellipse
$$w=x+iy,\quad\frac{(x-1)^2}9+y^2=1.$$

Does the downvoter need more details?
